# invoking perl scripts

Tags: perl

I have perl scripts starting with `#!/usr/bin/perl` or `#!/usr/bin/env perl`

First, what does the second version mean?

Second, I use Ubuntu. All the scripts are set as executables. When I try to run a script by simply invoking it's name (e.g. `./script.pl`) I get `: No such file or directory`. when I invoke by `perl ./script.pl` it runs fine.

Why?

Comment: Bit of a long shot -   are they scripts you have downloaded from somewhere and have you maybe got CR LF line endings in the file instead of LF  .

Comment: `which perl` says `/usr/bin/perl`. These are scripts I wrote (and still writing). I work solely on ubuntu.

Comment: that looks OK. try to run the script under [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) - to see actually what triggers the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#!/usr/bin/env perl` uses the standard POSIX tool `env` to work around the "problem" that UNIX doesn't support relative paths in shebang lines (AFAIK). The `env` tool can be used to start a program (in this case perl) after modifying environment variables. In this case, no variables are modified and `env` then searches the PATH for Perl and runs it. Thus a script with that particular shebang line will work even when Perl is not installed in `/usr/bin` but in some other path (which must be in the PATH variable).

Then, you problem with `./script.pl` not working: you said it has the executable bit(s) set, like with `chmod +x script.pl` ? But does it also start with a shebang (`#!`) line ? That is, the very first two bytes must be `#!` and it must be followed by a file path (to perl). That is necessary to tell the kernel with which program to run this script. If you have done so, is the path correct ? You want to try the `#!/usr/bin/env perl` variant ;-)

Comment: the very first line of the scripts is `#!/usr/bin/env perl`. I also tried replacing it with `#!/usr/bin/perl` (which indeed exists on my system) but that too didn't work with giving the same error message.

Comment: @David B: what `which env` and `which perl` say?

Comment: @Dummy00001: `$ which env` => `/usr/bin/env`, `$ which perl` => `/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: I get an error when I try to pass `-W` flag using /usr/bin/env whereas `/usr/bin/perl -W` works like a charm. Any workaround?

Comment: @Aif: What did you type exactly? `#!/usr/bin/env perl -W` should work.

Comment: @DarkDust exactly what I tried. I get `/usr/bin/env: perl -W: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Aif: Sorry, no idea. Better ask on SuperUser (this question should have been asked there to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

Using `#!/usr/bin/env perl` gets around the problem of `perl` not necessarily being in `/usr/bin` on every system; it's just there to make the script more portable

---

On a related note, for your second problem, is there a `/usr/bin/perl` and/or `/usr/bin/env`? If not, that would explain why running the scripts directly doesn't work; the shebang isn't handled if you run the script as an argument to `perl`

Comment: Just to clarify - if you run `perl script` it ignores any path in the shebang line but it does look at any option flags in the line.

Comment: Just to clarify the clarification with an edge case: If you run "perl script" it ignores any path in the shebang line if (and only if) the shebang line contains the word "perl".  If you put "#!/bin/sh" in there, perl is clever enough to execute sh for you.